# IST to dd/MM/yyyy format

Tags: angularjs, date-formatting

I'm trying to convert `Sun Dec 10 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` (getting from JSON) to `'dd/MM/yyyy'` format

In html `ng-repeat` I wrote like this `{{row.data | date:'dd/MM/yyyy''}}` but its not working. Please suggest me the way to convert only in html page.

Comment: what is there in the row.data? is it 'Sun Dec 10 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530'?

Comment: try`|date:'medium'`

Comment: @Rakesh Burbure Yes

Comment: you added an extra quote at end remove it `date:'dd/MM/yyyy''` change it to `date:'dd/MM/yyyy'`

Comment: your response would be string you need to convert it to date type to use date filter

Comment: @Edison It's not working.Actually date filter is only working on formats like 1288323623006.But im not understanding how to convert IST

Comment: use custom filter to make the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
item.date = $filter('date')(new Date(item.date), "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

in your controller.

You need to convert your date from `string` to `Javascript date object` to use the `date` filter.

**Update**

**Using a custom filter:**

```
app.filter('myFormat', function($filter) {
    return function(x) {
      return $filter('date')(new Date(x), "dd/MM/yyyy");

    };
});
```

and use this in html as:

```
{{row.data | myFormat}}
```

Comment: I know to how to convert in controller.But i'm trying for a way to do in html

Comment: I am not sure if there is any way to convert string to date object at html side,

other way you can do this by making a custom filter.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this below demo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
        {{date | mydate}}
    </div>

    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.filter('mydate', function ($filter) {
            return function (input) {
                return $filter('date')(new Date(input), "dd/MM/yyyy")
            }
        });
        app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.date = 'Sun Dec 10 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530';
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```